# XML Parsing with php not showing some tags data

Tags: php, rss, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to parse rss feed from a link. Here is my code:

```
            $content = file_get_contents($this->feed);     
            print_r($content);   
            $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
            print_r($rss);
            $rss_split = array();
           /* foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
                $title = (string) $item->title; // Title
                $link = (string) $item->link; // Url Link
                $description = (string) $item->description; //Description               
                $rss_split[] = '<div><a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" title="" >' . $title . ' </a><hr></div>';
            }*/
```

The full XML is being downloaded from here: http://devilsworkshop.org/feed/

Here is an excerpt to illustrate the structure:

```
<item>
    <title>Windows 8 Appstore resembles a ghost town</title>
    <link>http://devilsworkshop.org/windows-appstore-resembles-ghost-town/</link>
    <comments>http://devilsworkshop.org/windows-appstore-resembles-ghost-town/#comments</comments>
    <pubDate>Tue, 18 Sep 2012 05:30:22 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>Vibin</dc:creator>
    <category><![CDATA[Analysis]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[Windows 8]]></category>

    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://devilsworkshop.org/?p=62284</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>Microsoft is all set to release Windows 8 for public in the coming weeks. Apparently, the biggest change in Windows 8 seems to be the Metro UI (I know it&#8217;s no more called Metro, but let&#8217;s keep it like that [...]</p><p>--
            This Post <a href="http://devilsworkshop.org/windows-appstore-resembles-ghost-town/">Windows 8 Appstore resembles a ghost town</a> is Published on <a href="http://devilsworkshop.org">Devils Workshop</a> .
        </p><h3>Related posts:</h3><ul>
            <li><a href='http://devilsworkshop.org/googles-new-look-resembles-yahoo-search/' rel='bookmark' title='Google&#8217;s new look resembles Yahoo Search'>Google&#8217;s new look resembles Yahoo Search</a></li>
        </ul>]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Microsoft is all set to release Windows 8 for public in the coming weeks. Apparently, the biggest change in Windows 8 seems to be the Metro UI (I know it&#8217;s no more called Metro, but let&#8217;s keep it like that for simplicity) and apps.</p>
        <ul>
        <h2>Apps are less advanced</h2>
        <p>Metro is great on tablets, but on desktop, it looks like an OS with dumbed down apps. Take Skitch for example, it is an app for taking and editing screenshots and was previously a Mac-only app but recently came to Windows 8. Just compare these two apps and you&#8217;ll know what I meant.</p>
        <p>Here&#8217;s how Skitch looks in Windows 8:</p>
        <p><a href="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/SkitchinWindows8.png"><img style=' display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;'  class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-62302" title="SkitchinWindows8" src="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/SkitchinWindows8.png" alt="" width="740" height="570" /></a></p>
        <p>And now, this is the Mac version of Skitch:</p>
        <p><a href="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/SkitchinMac.png"><img style=' display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;'  class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-62301" title="SkitchinMac" src="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/SkitchinMac.png" alt="" width="671" height="575" /></a></p>
        <p>Another example can be Newsmix, an app which will let you read stuff that matters to you &#8211; in a Magazine layout. Apparently, this app is a fail for someone like me who subscribe to 50+ blogs.</p>
        <p><a href="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/NewsmixinWindows8.png"><img style=' display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;'  class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-62305" title="NewsMix in Windows 8" src="http://devilsworkshop.org/files/2012/09/NewsmixinWindows8-1024x640.png" alt="news-mix-windows-8" width="620" height="387" /></a><br />
            Sure, it will be great on a Windows slate, but not really on a PC/laptop.</p>
        <li><a href='http://devilsworkshop.org/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-windows-vistawindows-7/' rel='bookmark' title='How to enable Hibernate Option in Windows Vista/Windows 7'>How to enable Hibernate Option in Windows Vista/Windows 7</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://devilsworkshop.org/windows-store/' rel='bookmark' title='Microsoft to Introduce Windows Store with Windows 8 Platform'>Microsoft to Introduce Windows Store with Windows 8 Platform</a></li>
        </ul>]]>
    </content:encoded>          
    <wfw:commentRss>http://devilsworkshop.org/windows-appstore-resembles-ghost-town/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

When I'm printing `$content` it is showing the Images from the `content:encoded` tag.
But Printing `$rss` not showing that tag at all and description tag is also showing `SimpleXMLElement Object()`.

I want to parse both tag. where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please give us the rest of your code.  It makes easier to debug, rather than working with incomplete code which is rife with errors.

Comment: $this->feed= file name only...

Comment: I'm talking about your namespace declarations.  You have namespaces in your xml document but nowhere do I see any declarations..

Comment: I'm getting this xml file from this link : http://devilsworkshop.org/feed/

Comment: And that actually declares the namespaces.  A moment while I debug.

Comment: Just to confirm, is `$description = (string) $item->description;` returning the expected data?

Comment: @Ravi I have debugged and updated my answer; please see it for a working solution.

Comment: @IMSoP> yes it is returning expected data..

Comment: @Daedalus> after applying your solution it is showing blank page if printing ($rss);

Comment: @Ravi I find that odd; it's working fine for me.  To be clear, are you `print()`ing $rss, or `print_r()`ing $rss?  All `print()` does is echo a string.. if the content is a string.  You need to use `print_r()` to see human-readable information regarding objects and arrays.  That's what print_r does.

Comment: @Daedalus To reiterate my comments elsewhere, even `print_r` will **not** give you an accurate picture of a SimpleXML object. You will see that it is a SimpleXML object, but not a lot else.

Comment: @Daedalus> I'm using **print_r($rss)**.  If I uncomment the below code after adding your code(foreach loop), result is blank page only

Comment: is it because of **<content:encoded>**???

Comment: @Ravi Have you looked at my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `print_r()` is not a good choice for predicting how a SimpleXML object will behave, as they are not "normal" PHP objects. You could try [my `simplexml_dump()` function](http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug), which lists the content, children, and attributes of a particular node or list of nodes.

Secondly, the `content:encoded` element is in the namespace `content`, so you need to tell SimpleXML to access nodes in that namespace rather than the default using the [`->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php). e.g. `echo $item->children('content', true)->encoded;`

Comment: > Thanks $item->children('content', true)->encoded; worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course printing `$rss` isn't showing the data.. it's showing what it's meant to, given it itself is indeed a `SimpleXMLElement Object`.

That aside, however, from what I can tell, your xml document is failing to parse because it is not valid `UTF-8`.  Upon copying it to my client, and combing through it, I found a bunch of `xA0` and `x92` characters.

Upon replacing them each with their corresponding characters(space and apostrophe) and saving the document, it parsed fine.

This is most surely your problem.

A solution to this problem is as follows:

```
$char_arr = array('/\xa0/','/\x92/','/\x96/');
$rep_arr = array('&nbsp;','\'','-');
$content = preg_replace($char_arr, $rep_arr, $content);
```

Make sure you place this code before your declaration of your simpleXML object:

```
$content = file_get_contents($this->feed);     
print_r($content);
$char_arr = array('/\xa0/','/\x92/','/\x96/');
$rep_arr = array('&nbsp;','\'','-');
$content = preg_replace($char_arr, $rep_arr, $content);
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
```

That should solve your problem; tested it myself, it worked on my end.

Comment: The embedded HTML in this case is inside a CDATA block, so the XML will be valid however mangled the HTML gets - as long as it doesn't contain the string `]]>`, which would end the CDATA block prematurely.

Comment: @IMSoP Well, in that case, I debugged again, and I believe this time, found the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to IMSoP answer, I have followed straight to http://php.net/simplexml where xaviered_at gmail_dot_com's xmlObjToArr($obj) function been found and used, instead, to solve the same matter.

Here's is short and obvious script for those, who are still looking a simple way to get content tagged between content:encoded

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";

$url = "http://devilsworkshop.org/feed/";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

if($rss){

    $items = $rss->channel->item;

    foreach($items as $item){

        $title = $item->title;
        $image = $item->image;
        $link = $item->link;
        $published_on = $item->pubDate;
        $description = $item->description;

        // bringing in to array <content:encoded> items from SimpleXMLElement Object()
        $content = xmlObjToArr($item->children('content', true)->encoded);


        echo "

        title: $title
        image: $image
        link: $link
        published on: $published_on
        description: $description
        content: 
        ";

        print_r($content);

    }
}


function xmlObjToArr($obj) {
        $namespace = $obj->getDocNamespaces(true);
        $namespace[NULL] = NULL;

        $children = array();
        $attributes = array();
        $name = strtolower((string)$obj->getName());

        $text = trim((string)$obj);
        if( strlen($text) <= 0 ) {
            $text = NULL;
        }

        // get info for all namespaces
        if(is_object($obj)) {
            foreach( $namespace as $ns=>$nsUrl ) {
                // atributes
                $objAttributes = $obj->attributes($ns, true);
                foreach( $objAttributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue ) {
                    $attribName = strtolower(trim((string)$attributeName));
                    $attribVal = trim((string)$attributeValue);
                    if (!empty($ns)) {
                        $attribName = $ns . ':' . $attribName;
                    }
                    $attributes[$attribName] = $attribVal;
                }

                // children
                $objChildren = $obj->children($ns, true);
                foreach( $objChildren as $childName=>$child ) {
                    $childName = strtolower((string)$childName);
                    if( !empty($ns) ) {
                        $childName = $ns.':'.$childName;
                    }
                    $children[$childName][] = xmlObjToArr($child);
                }
            }
        }

        return array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'text'=>$text,
            'attributes'=>$attributes,
            'children'=>$children
        );
    }


?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to recover any actual DC data. The arrays always return blank, and never contain content like `dc:creator`